# I’m looping through a database but my div model only works for the first record and not the others

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, loops

I found a model over at w3 schools that suits my needs, but when i loop through my database the model only works on the first result, it's probably the javascript, but i'm very inexperienced with js. would somebody be able to give me some pointers please?

My project consists of the HTML bellow just a lot more of it.
HTML/PHP:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($results as $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="openModel">open the model</div>
                    <!-- The Modal -->
                    <div id="updateModel" class="modal">

                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p><?php echo $value["col1"]; ?></p>
                            <p><?php echo $value["col2"]; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

JS:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("updateModel");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("openModel");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #c4c4c4;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Modal Header */
.modal-header {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #6d6d6d;
    color: white;
}

/* Modal Body */
.modal-body {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}

/* Modal Footer */
.modal-footer {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #6d6d6d;
    color: white;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@keyframes animatetop {
from {
top: -300px; opacity: 0}
to {top: 0; opacity: 1}
}
```

Comment: Each id must be unique. When you iterate through your loop, each modal has the same `openModel` and `updateModel` id. You'll need to create a unique id for each.

Comment: @aynber could you help a little more please? The js part is really confusing. I’ve put my code in a pastebin https://pastebin.com/Ci7Sufer I’m getting a broken model that won’t close and all my rows are opening the same result

Comment: Your models are probably named right, now, but you're overwriting the vars on each loop. You can probably add the id to the variable names, but that also means creating a lot of repeated code. I'm trying to remember the easier way to do it, which I think involves the `data-attribute`, but I can't remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, you have to use different IDs for each element. That's why this only work with the last element.

Also, you are only getting one elementById ONCE. Thus, the JS code will only work with just one element.

Also, `span` variable is only the first "X" on the document. Other "X" will have no onClick events.

I've done the work for you but this is a quite simple approach. **This is not the best solution but the quickest I've thinked of.** I don't like the `window.onclick` part, expecially the conditional but, hey, it works.

HTML/PHP

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($results as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div><span id="openModal-<?= $key ?>" class="openModal" onclick="openModal('updateModal<?= $key ?>')">open the modal</span></div>
                    <!-- The Modal -->
                    <div id="updateModal<?= $key ?>" class="modal">

                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <span class="close" onclick="closeModal('updateModal<?= $key ?>')">&times;</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p><?php echo $value["col1"]; ?></p>
                            <p><?php echo $value["col2"]; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

JS

```
<script>
function openModal(id) {
    console.log(id);
    var modal = document.getElementById(id);
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
function closeModal(id) {
    var modal = document.getElementById(id);
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// This may be the worst part of the code.
window.onclick = function(event) {
    var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
    if (event.target.className.indexOf('close') == -1 && event.target.className.indexOf('openModal') == -1 && event.target.className.indexOf('modal') == -1) {
        for (var i = modals.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            modals[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

---

**Note**: I've not used the CSS part so I don't know if it also needs some corrections.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much. Do you happen to know how i can close the model on mobile Safari by clicking outside of the model window.

Comment: @Benwhittaker25 I like using vanilla JS whenever is possible, but why don't you use some library for modals? There are plenty of them: [MicroModal](https://micromodal.now.sh/), [jQueryModal](https://jquerymodal.com/)...

Comment: I will look into js more closely , I’ve been meaning to study up on it next anyway; jquery in  particular, I see it a lot on my raspberry pi.